# Flip UIView with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift

I try to flip a View that has rounded corners (borders).

[image: Rounded Corners]

The round corners of the view are implemented with:

```
  private extension UIView {

  func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let mask = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
    addBorder(mask: mask, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: borderWidth)
}

        @discardableResult func _round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            self.layer.mask = mask
            return mask
        }

        func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
            let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            borderLayer.path = mask.path
            borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
            borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
            borderLayer.frame = bounds
            layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        }

    }
```

The flip is implemented with

```
UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight], animations: {}, completion: {_ in })
```

While the flip is running, the boarders are not rounded anymore while the transition is running.

[image]

Anybody has an idea how to do the flip, without loosing the round corners?

**Update**

If I go for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727356/how-do-you-flip-non-fullscreen-uiviews-in-a-superview-with-rounded-corners) approach, I have several problems.

The flip is now implemented like this:

```
  let flipAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        flipAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
        flipAnimation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0,1,0))
        flipAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

        self.layer.add(flipAnimation, forKey: "flip")
        self.layer.zPosition = -1000

        CATransaction.commit()
```

**Problems**

- Animation isn't that smooth like UIView.transition
- The effect mirrors the content on the view --> I don't need that (image below)
- The rotation does not end exactly, so the views are misplaced sometimes (image below)

[image: Mirrored 7 on the view]
[image: position of the view after rotation]

**Update: Solution**
I added a Container-View around the colored view with the rounded corners and flipped the container instead of the colored view. Then everything works fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you flip non-fullscreen UIView's in a superview with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727356/how-do-you-flip-non-fullscreen-uiviews-in-a-superview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: I updated the question, thx for your hint.

Comment: How do you want the view to look after it has been rotated?

Comment: I change the content of the label and the background color while the animation is running so it looks like the back side of the element has another color and another content of the label. But technically it is the same side and the same label you see after the flip.

Comment: I got something for you if you give me a bit. Do you update the label after the green view spins or when it spins around it is a new value?

Comment: Directly after UIView.transition / CATransaction.commit() , but it looks like the value changes when the View is a line at 90 degree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to add the view you want to flip to a clear view and flip the parent that is holding it. I think it is something to do with the layer being rerendered but not totally sure.  Here is a working example using a CATransition but my guess is other methods would work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var label = UILabel()
    var flipper = UIView()
    var flipperContainer = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        flipperContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
        flipperContainer.backgroundColor = .clear
        flipperContainer.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(flipperContainer)

        flipper = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
        flipper.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        flipper.round(corners: [UIRectCorner.topLeft,UIRectCorner.topRight], radius: 6, borderColor: .white, borderWidth: 1)
        self.flipperContainer.addSubview(flipper)



        //add a label
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: flipper.bounds.width, height: flipper.bounds.height))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.center = flipper.center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.text = "7"

        flipper.addSubview(label)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


        let flipButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 50))
        flipButton.center = flipperContainer.center
        flipButton.center.y = flipperContainer.center.y + flipperContainer.bounds.height/2 + 20
        flipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        flipButton.setTitle("Flip", for: .normal)
        flipButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)

        self.view.addSubview(flipButton)
    }

    func pressed(sender:UIButton) {

        let trans = CATransition()
        trans.duration = 1.0
        trans.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        trans.type = "flip"
        trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        //perform flip but on container
        flipperContainer.layer.add(trans, forKey: nil)

        if flipper.backgroundColor == UIColor.green{
            flipper.backgroundColor = .blue
            label.text = "20"
        }else{
            flipper.backgroundColor = .green
            label.text = "7"
        }
    }

}
```

I am using your extension to round the corners.  I tried to replicate what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Adding a flip-container around the colored & rounded view did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sialcasa glad it helped. Cheers

Comment: Great solution. I added parent view and it works very well. I confirm that it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to set the background of the view to an image of the desired color with the corners rounded in the image, as opposed to setting the background to a color and rounding the corners in code.

Comment: This is no option, because the color of the element has to be generated randomly.